# How do i change Date Format in Month Day, Year in C#

Tags: c#

I have a Following line of code. The Date of string type is in the format `29/11/2017`.
        I wanted it as `November 29, 2017`.
         I tried adding String.Format but it display the same 29/11/2017 in pdf.

```
cellValDate.AddElement(new Phrase(String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}",
                       txtDate.Text, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")), 
                       new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 
                       10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)));
```

Comment: You need to parse your string into a `DateTime` first.  You're attempting to format a string using datetime format strings.  C# has no reason to think that string contains a date.

Comment: Why have you tagged export-to-pdf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to parse and convert the date string value in `txtDate.Text` to a `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Then convert it to the particular format- "Month Day, Year".

```
string formateDate = dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

Then you can pass it to your code-

```
cellValDate.AddElement(new Phrase(formateDate, 
                        new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 
                        10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)));
```

Comment: Thank u so much Souvik..It Worked Perfectly....:)
i am getting the same issue in one more situation.Here sent_date is of type date and its format is MM/DD/YYYY in excel.I am reading the sent_date from excel(10/29/2017) and assigning it to ex_date. here i got error as "string is not recoqnized as valid datetime"..why it is so? I have used Datetime.Parse.

string ex_date = dr[2].ToString();
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(ex_date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?sentdate", date);

Comment: @chetan - Please don't ask follow up questions in comments. Ask a new question.

Comment: @chetan Hi. Am glad it worked. As per Stackoverflow rules we do not ask question in "comments" section as it loses the visibility in sometime. I would recommend you to post a new question so that we can help and your question may help other people with similar issues.

Comment: @chetan - I read your comment - it's not carrying on a conversation regarding the current question, it's asking a new one.

Comment: ok @SouvikGhosh and Enigmativity..:) I will post a new question regarding that.